# 2005 Suburban rear passenger window drops about 6 inches.

Tags: chevrolet, power-windows, suburban

I have tried duct-tape, messy and ongoing, Paint sticks as shims with and added a slice of rubber between glass and wood. This held up for weeks. Now I need to buy the part and replace via YouTube. There is the power motor which still makes noise likes it works, and the regulator. Which does this problem need to be applied to resolve issue.  Should I replace the motor, regulator, or both?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem most likely resides in the motor worm gear, but you won't know for sure until you get it apart. The regulator in the truck is a cable driven one. It looks like this:

[image]

The motor attaches to the doohicky on the left side. The window slides are directly attached to the cables within the supports. If the cable system were to fail, the window would most likely not move at all or drop all the way to the bottom. Like I said, there's no real way to tell (that I know of) until you get it apart.

My suggestion to you if your pocket book can handle it is to buy both parts (regulator and motor). Then, when you pull the door panel apart to replace whatever's wrong, you can figure out which part(s) you'll need. If you only need one of the two, return the other for a refund. Just check the return policy of wherever you're looking at to purchase the parts to see if they will take it back, no questions asked. Some parts stores won't take electrical items back, so ensure you read the fine print.

The reason I suggest this route is if you get one part, but you need the other, your door is going to be either torn apart until you get the part you need, or you'll have to put it all back together with the broken parts to wait for the replacements. You may consider it a good move to just replace both parts in the first place and call it a day.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like one or more of the runners has jumped out of its rail inside the door (these are either lever driven or cable driven) - usually if the "bearing" is still in good condition it can be put back into place and it should work. Sometimes to get the bearing back into place the mechanism needs to be disconnected so the bearing can "travel" further to enter the channel it runs in.

If it is all too worn then you need a new mechanism.